# densityplot and stripplot with mice object

Tags: r, lattice, density-plot, r-mice

I am using the densityplot and stripplot functions to analyze the results of a mice imputation. My data set has 30 variables. When applying densityplot and stripplot to the mice object containing the results of the imputation, I obtain a panel with the graphs for each of the variables. All the graphs are contained in only one panel (one for the densityplot and other one for the stipplot function) and to get it the size of the graphs is really very small, making almost imposible to differentiate and analyze the information of each of the graphs. Densityplot and stripplot are used as follows:

densityplot(tempData)

stripplot(tempData, pch = 20, cex = 1.2)

tempData is the mice object with the imputations. It contains more than 30 variables.

I would like to know if there is any option to control the number of graphs by panel when using densityplot and stripplot. In my case, if I split tho output of these functions in several panels, the graphs for each variable should be bigger enough to analyze it properly.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

These functions follow the `lattice` conventions. So you should look into the documentation of that R package.

For a `ggplot2` alternative to the plotting functions, see the `plot_imps()` function in this repo (under development!): https://github.com/amices/shinymice/blob/main/R/utils_04_imputations.R

Comment: Hi Hanne. Thanks for your suggestion. Can you suggest me any good reference to dive into lattice in order to try to handle this issue?

Comment: Probably too late, but for the next person landing on this page: see https://mgimond.github.io/ES218/Week04b.html#Customizing_trellis_plots